# Make it unable to kick/ban mods with discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am a beginner discord bot creator, (my first bot actually) so this might be a dumb question but I just do not know how to make it that you can't kick/ban anyone with the 'ADMINISTRATOR' role. My code so far:

```js
const { MessageManager } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",

    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            if (!message.member.roles.cache.has("845966863070789644") && !message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                message.channel.send(`You can't kick mods`);
            } else {
                memberTarget.kick();
                message.channel.send("Sure. See you later.");
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`I was unable to execute that command -.-`);
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should stop the ability of kicking member with the Administrator permissions. For the role, replace `memberTarget.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")` with `memberTarget.roles.caches.find(i => i.name.toUpperCase() === "ADMINISTRATOR")`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            if (memberTarget.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                message.channel.send(`You can't kick mods`);
            } else {
                memberTarget.kick();
                message.channel.send("Sure. See you later.");
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`I was unable to execute that command -.-`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Except [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does not accept a function as parameter. That would be a job for [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if they're **not** a mod before telling the user that they can't kick mods. Therefore, you can **only** kick mods. Also, don't check for ADMINISTRATOR and a role, just check for ADMINISTRATOR permission, because it's simpler and doing it otherwise is bulkly. Here's a correction (note that I haven't tested this code yet, but I've used similar code before):

```
const { MessageManager } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",

    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            if (message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                message.channel.send(`You can't kick mods`);
            } else {
                memberTarget.kick();
                message.channel.send("Sure. See you later.");
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`I was unable to execute that command -.-`);
        }
    },
};
```